# datagridview to crystal report with inner join

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview, crystal-reports

I am creating Crystal Reports from datagridview data ..
The Data in datagridview are appearing but when I press the btnPreview Only the Column name in Crystal Reports are showing. 
Data in Datagridview (Columns and Rows) is OK but the only thing appears in my Crystal report is only the Column names ..
tables are connected with inner join
here is my code

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    dt.Columns.Add("Prepares.OrderID")
    dt.Columns.Add("Prepares.EmployeeId")
    dt.Columns.Add("Employees.Firstname")
    dt.Columns.Add("Employees.Lastname")
    dt.Columns.Add("Prepares.OrderDate")
    dt.Columns.Add("Prepares.Subtotal")
    dt.Columns.Add("Prepares.Amount")

    For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows()
        dt.Rows.Add(dr.Cells("OrderID").Value, dr.Cells("EmployeeId").Value, dr.Cells("Firstname").Value, _
                     dr.Cells("Lastname").Value, dr.Cells("Subtotal").Value, dr.Cells("Amount").Value)
    Next
    Dim rptDoc As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    rptDoc = New CrystalReport2
    rptDoc.SetDataSource(dt)
    CrystalReportViewer.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc
    CrystalReportViewer.ShowDialog()
    CrystalReportViewer.Dispose()
```

P.S
- Pardon my English. I'm not good at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal Reports, in my experiences, is looking for the tables that the data originated from not the combined data table. My suggestion would be to send it the individual tables and that should solve the problem.

Comment: how? my way of creating crystal reports is like

Comment: how sir? cause this type of crystal report i am creating is that the Datagridview will only send its Data to Crystalreport

Comment: ok, I thought you were pulling the data from a database. Since you aren't, you need to create a dataset in the project and then point the crystal report to that dataset for its data fields. Once that is done you should be ale to place the data fields where you want on the report. If you have already done that, then is there any custom code behind the crystal report that would cause the fields to not print out?